# Plugin management in maven

Tags: maven, plugins, ant

Can you please suggest how to do plugin management in maven.
I have to call the below code

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <ant antfile="${basedir}/build/build.xml">
                                    <target name="${ant.mode}" />
                                </ant>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

In some of the  the submodule in a multi maven project module.
Can you suggest how to integrate this in only selective maven profiles?
Any Help will be appreciated .
```

Can some one suggest any solution for plugin management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the configuration into the parent into pluginManagement.

Either you specify the plugin (without configuration) in each module where you need it, or you use the `skip` parameter to activate/deactivate the plugin.